# Ruby On Rails: how can I render a partial inside a loop using js.haml?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to render a partial for every object in array of hashes:

My controller:

```
@active, @not_active = @objects.partition{ |obj| obj['active'] == 'true' }
```

My `js.haml` file:

```
# this code works
- @active.each do |obj|
  $('#' + "#{obj['id']}").remove(); # remove row

# this code doesn't work
- @not_active.each do |obj|
  -p obj # prints the object
  $('#' + "#{obj['id']}").html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'objects/not_active', :locals => {:obj => obj})}");
```

This code should redraw some of the existing rows in a table. But In the partial I get obj = [ ] instead of the hash..

How else can I render the partial inside a ruby loop?

Comment: I don't know haml, but usually local variables in rails are ruby instance variables (start with @).  So change obj to @obj?

Comment: Thanks, but inside the loop I don't need @. Anyway, it gives me an error - formal argument cannot be an instance variable..

Answer (score 0):

There's a more concise way to render partials and pass data to it:

```
render 'objects/not_active', obj: obj
```

Not sure if this is rails 4 only.